# How to change the repository location while installing from live cd?

Tags: apt, system-installation, live-usb, software-sources

I am installing 14.04 from a live CD. While installing, it downloads updates from the Internet. I see it is currently downloading from

```
http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/
```

Is there any way I can change that repo? My company has Ubuntu mirrored on an internal repository, and I would like to use that.

I tried changing in `/etc/apt/sources.lst` , but the installer doesn't respect that file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the mirror manually in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but I'm not sure if the installer respects that file. (Although, why wouldn't it?)

Another approach would be to disable updates during installation, and just set up the mirror once the installation is done.

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't respect that file.

Answer (score 0):

1. First step: add your CD / DVD to the sources list.

Option A: Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment all the repositories excepting the CD with:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Option B: Use `apt-cdrom`

```
test: sudo apt-cdrom --no-act add
```

If everything is OK:

```
sudo apt-cdrom add
sudo apt-cdrom ident
sudo apt-cdrom -d "your-cdrom-mount-point" -r
```

2. Second step: update with: `sudo apt-get update`
3. Now install the packages you want to - for example `apt-get install packagename`

Comment: I dont want to use the CD as the update source. I want to download the repos of an internal mirror hosted locally(Saves bandwidth, is ultra fast). Anyway, I installed and changed the download locations later.